# How to send input to search bar that is part of overlap using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to automate using the search bar of this website: [Economic Times of India](https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/hdfc-bank-ltd/stocks/companyid-9195.cms)

I can locate the search icon and click it but then the actual search bar comes up and I cannot seem to send input to it. Below is my code:

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


website = webdriver.Chrome()
website.get("https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/hdfc-bank-ltd/stocks/companyid-9195.cms")

#button = website.find_element(By.ID, "searchBar")

search_button = WebDriverWait(website, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (
            By.ID,
            "searchBar",
        )
    )
)

search_button.click()

search_bar = WebDriverWait(website, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (
            By.ID,
            "topSearch",
        )
    )
)

search_bar.send_keys("Asian Paints")
```

The above code results in an ElementNotInteractable error. I'm new to Selenium so I'm guessing I'm not locating the search bar correctly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found my error so will post here-- I did not locate the search bar correctly. Below is corrected code:

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


website = webdriver.Chrome()
website.get("https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/hdfc-bank-ltd/stocks/companyid-9195.cms")

#button = website.find_element(By.ID, "searchBar")

search_icon = WebDriverWait(website, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (
            By.ID,
            "searchBar",
        )
    )
)

search_icon.click()

search_bar = WebDriverWait(website, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (
            By.CLASS_NAME,
            "inputBox",
        )
    )
)


#search_bar.is_displayed()
search_bar.send_keys("Asian Paints")

search_button = WebDriverWait(website, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (
            By.CLASS_NAME,
            "srch-btn.btn",
        )
    )
)

search_button.click()
```